# Foreach through JSONArray in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [page].php on line 49

This is an echo of the $json variable:
`[{"d":"2011-03-26","q":1,"t":1060},{"d":"2011-03-26","q":2,"t":1060},{"d":"2011-03-26","q":1,"t":1060}]`

And I'm trying to iterate through like so:

```
foreach($json as $obj) { // <--THIS IS LINE 49
    // Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess:

Your `$json` variable is a string. You'll need to convert it to an object using `json_decode` to iterate through the object:

```
$json_obj = json_decode( $json );
foreach( $json_obj as $obj )
{
  //stuff
}
```

Comment: Ahh, Thanks. I knew it was something simple. The previous line was `$json = base64_decode($json);` So it would output a string.

Answer (score 1):

you have to [decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json before you can iterate it.

The JSON-String itself is meaningless to foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `json_decode()` first. It looks like your variable is json encoded, which means it's really just a string, and therefore not enumerable by foreach.

```
foreach(json_decode($json) as $obj) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach(json_decode($json) as $obj) {
    // stuff
}`

It returns me a Warning like this : Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), although works.

My code is here:

```
function search_terms ( $json , $term ) 
        {
            if ( $json != null ){
                foreach ( $json as $item ) {// Recursive function
                    $this->search_terms ( $item, $term );
                }
            }else{

            }
        }
```