# Get list of top friends for facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am Creating A facebook that Retrieves 10 Random friends.But I need some code to Retrieve Top friends using comment and like ativity.I used Following code but i get below error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

below is the code i tried so far.

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');

    foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
    // processing likes array for calculating fanbase. 

            foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){
                $frid = $likesData['id']; 
                $frname = $likesData['name']; 
                $friendArray[$frid] = $frname;
            }

     foreach($status['comments']['data'] as $comArray){
     // processing comments array for calculating fanbase
                $frid = $comArray['from']['id'];
                $frname = $comArray['from']['name'];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message generally happens when your array variable is not set. If you could add line numbers to your code and give the full error message (including line number) it might help.

Can you show a print_r of $statuses['data']?

Comment: thank you..i found the sloution..i was not getting user_status permission.now problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get this to work myself.  Found the solution.  `$facebook->api()` is going to return a json array.  This is not a valid element for a `foreach()` statement.  You need to use `json_decode($statuses)` in order to loop through the array in the `foreach()` statement.

[Foreach through JSONArray in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444260/foreach-through-jsonarray-in-php)