# Retrieve top 10 friends of user on Facebook (get their UIDs) PHP, Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**How do I get a user's top 10 friends' uids**, and wrap each uid with specified string?

From: [Get list of top friends for facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9407379/1399030), I see this:

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');

foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
// processing likes array for calculating fanbase. 

        foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){
            $frid = $likesData['id']; 
            $frname = $likesData['name']; 
            $friendArray[$frid] = $frname;
        }

 foreach($status['comments']['data'] as $comArray){
 // processing comments array for calculating fanbase
            $frid = $comArray['from']['id'];
            $frname = $comArray['from']['name'];

}
```

But what does that return? Does it return the user IDs of friends in an array? I would like to get it in an array, the result of the search, so I can wrap each ID using foreach and do what I please with it.

If the above code is enough, should I be calling `$frid` for the array of top friends? I just need comprehension. **:o)**

Thank you for your time.

---

**Assume that permissions are granted.**
(This happens only after the user allows permission, so assume we already have that.)

Comment: Examine the return with `var_dump($statuses['data'])` or just `var_dump($statuses)`.

Comment: If you’re not sure about the return type of anything in PHP, please use var_dump, it’ll tell you.

Comment: Thank you guys, it returned `array(0) { } ` ... So, what to do? :)

Comment: **var_dump($statuses)** returns `array(1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } } ` while **var_dump($statuses['data'])** returns `array(0) { }`

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a valid access token. See the [Authentication section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) on the developer site. [Authenticating as an app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) is the easiest way if you're new at this.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you have the latest SDK by going to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/zipball/master

Unzip and you have a layout as shown below

```
/facebook-php-sdk
index.php
```

Where index.php with the file being used to display in the browser the number of friends

Include the SDK at the start of the PHP file

```
require('sdk/src/facebook.php');
```

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps, select your app and get your App ID and App Secret, create an instance within the PHP file

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_HERE',
));
```

Then retrieve the `$user` data so we know that the current user is authenticated

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Before sending any calls check whether the authentication was right

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Now make a call to `/me/statuses` the documentation is available at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#statuses

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
```

This should return an array of the structure Status message defined at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/ of all the current user status messages.

Now you need to decide what determines top friends

- number of likes + comments
- number of comments
- number of likes

Let's choose option 1, and give each weight of 1. That is a like and a comment are equivalent in value for determining the amount of friends

So create a variable to hold this, for example $friendArray

Then make an iteration over all the status messages but the entire JSON reponse starts with a wrapped `data`

```
{
  "data": [
```

So access `$statuses['data']`, the foreach will give all status messages as a `status` item

```
foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
```

Within this loop iterate all the likes and increment the value of each id that appears

```
foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){
    $frid = $likesData['id']; 
    $friendArray[$frid] = $friendArray[$frid] + 1;
}
```

Within this loop iterate all the comments and increment the value of each id that appears

```
foreach($status['comments']['data'] as $comArray){
    $frid = $comArray['from']['id'];
    $friendArray[$frid] = $friendArray[$frid] + 1;
}
```

At the end of the outer loop `foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){` you should have the an array `$friendArray` which has the scores.

Call `asort` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php to sort the array and you can then loop for the top x scores.

The code you showed isn't a function and is actually missing a closing brace, it does not actually return anything as it is not a function.

**Caveats**: The `/me/statuses` only returns a limited set of status messages per call you need to get `previous` page calls to iterate *all* your messages. The top friends returned are only based on the restriction I made up above.